# how do you spread processing intensive work over time in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have some loops that run for a long time.

Running processing intensive code can slow down the PC or device quite a bit, and make it unresponsive. I would rather it take a bit longer and give a response of how fa along it is to being done.

How do I limit the calculations to fit within the processing timeframe of a single frame whatever is running it?

Comment: There is the whole `Worker` bit – I haven't had occasion to use those. I suppose dead simple, you could use an `enterFrame` event and do one iteration of a loop (or break out the code to be a function that takes an index, per frame.

Comment: Worker in not supported on iOS. While I could use it with a fallback, I'd rather just handle it the same way if possible

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted your processing code to run once at the time of a single frame, first you need to calculate how long a single frame takes in your script;

```
    public var startTimer:Number=0;
    public var singleFrameTime:Number=0;
```

In `Main`:

```
startTimer=getTimer();
```

Then at the bottom of your function triggered by an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event;

```
singleFrameTime = getTimer()-startTimer;
```

This gets you the time in milliseconds of a single frame.

So now, using the `Timer` class, you can create a timer;

```
var frameTimer:Timer = new Timer(singleFrameTime);
```

Now add a listener to it and start the timer;

```
frameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, excecute);
frameTimer.start();
```

Where `execute()` is your function that will run your code once in the time it took for a single frame to render.

If you want to constantly update the `Timer` to the time it takes for a single frame to render in your script, then you can change the timer interval with the `frameTimer.delay`. If you need to capture the time between each frame multiple times, you'll have to calculate the delay within the Event.ENTER_FRAME function itself.

If you want a more smooth execution time, then get the total the `singleFrameTime` 60 frames at a time, and then average the result to get the average frame time.